# Integrating vertically giving different answer from intergrating horizontal

Tags: definite-integrals

> [image]
> Find area in the region: $$ \frac{1}{x} <y < x^{\frac13}$$ , $1
> <x<8$

So, I thought of integrating 'vertically' by:

$$ \int y dx = xy - \int x dy =16- \left[ \int_1^2 y^3 + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} dy\right] $$

Now, the problem is that $ \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{y}$ part, it seems to blow up. So, this method seems unfeasible, is there are any reason I could 'remove' the blow up and what exactly is the property of the function which causes this to occur?

Note the integral $ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} dy$ represents this following area:
[image]

Comment: Consider $1<x<8$ instead.

Comment: @player3236 my bad. fixed.

Comment: Then there is no reason for $\int_0^1 \frac1y dy$ to exist in your steps, and everything should converge.

Comment: You have the integrals wrong. The region that you are highlighting needs to be split into $2$. One is a rectangle plus the area under the curve. $y \ne 0$ for the area under the curve.

Comment: the red portion goes all the way to infinity, doesn't it @Math Lover

Comment: No but $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} dy$ does not represent the area that you are claiming. at $x=8, y = 1/8$ so the lower bound of $y$ is $1/8$ and then below that you have a rectangular area.

Comment: Ohhhhh @MathLover I don't know why but I kept putting the other functions bound into it. Thank you I understood my mistake now.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertically:

$$\int_{1/8}^1 (8-1/y) \ dy + \int_{1}^2 (8-y^3) \ dy$$

Horizontally:

$$\int_{1}^8 (x^{1/3}-1/x) \ dx$$

Comment: Hmm where did you get the eight from?

Comment: If integrating vertically it's a function of $y$. The right-most bound of your region is $x=8$, and the left-most splits between your two functions at $y=1$.

Comment: Hmm right, but I think this is giving me a different answer from the regular method, the whole rectangles area I got as: $(8-1)( 2 - \frac{1}{8})$ and I subtract $\int_{\frac18} \frac{1}{y} dy + \int_1^2 (y^3) dy$.

Comment: Both integrals are the shaded area you give, and are equal to $45/4-\ln(8)$

Comment: 8-1 is the length of rectangle along x , and 2-1/8 is width of rectangle along y

Comment: I don;t know why you're concerned with the "rectangle"--it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I basically screwed up the figure,  the figure in the question goes from $0 $ to $8$ but we want from $1$ to $8$

[image]

The area of rectangle is given as $2 \cdot 8$

[image]

The blue area is given as:

$$ \int_1^2 y^3 dy $$

And the purple given as:

$$ \int_{\frac18}^1 \frac{1}{y} dy$$

Putting it together

$$ \text{required area} = 2 \cdot 16 -  \int_1^2 y^3 dy - \int_{\frac18}^1 \frac{1}{y} dy$$

And this gives the same as David P's answer